# ChefSpec - Can i mock UserID (owner)? i get Chef::Exceptions::UserIDNotFound

Tags: chef-infra, chefspec

i'm testing a recipe that create few file with `owner "dev"` and getting this exception:

```
Chef::Exceptions::UserIDNotFound
--------------------------------
cannot determine user id for 'dev', does the user exist on this system?
```

now, in another recipe i install a deb file that creates that user.
is there a way to mock it during the test run ?

**Update - Sharing a code snippet:**

this is a part of my recipe `my_cookbook::configure.rb` that i am testing with ChefSpec:

```rb
# Code that iterates cluster members with some logic querying Chef Server (until it finds all of them)
....

#define my_service so we can notify it config is changed
#note that i do that to make the tests happy as this service is being installed in another recipe by a .deb file
service "my_service" do
  action :nothing
end

template "#{node[:my_service][:config_file]}" do
  source "my_service.conf.erb"
  owner "dev" # <-- this throws an exception during chefspec test run
  group "dev"
  mode "0644"
  notifies :restart, 'service[my_service]', :delayed 
  variables(
      {
          :node_id => node_id,
          :cluster_members => cluster_nodes,
      }
  )
end
```

and the test:

```rb
  def get_cluster_members_stubs
  [stub_node("my_service_node1.us.example.com",
             platform: 'ubuntu',
             version: '14.04',
             ohai: {
                 hostname: 'my_service_node1',
                 ipaddress: '1.2.3.4'
             }),
   stub_node("my_service_node2.us.example.com",
             platform: 'ubuntu',
             version: '14.04',
             ohai: {
                 hostname: 'my_service_node2',
                 ipaddress: '1.2.3.5'
             }),
   stub_node("my_service_node3.us.example.com",
             platform: 'ubuntu',
             version: '14.04',
             ohai: {
                 hostname: 'my_service_node3',
                 ipaddress: '1.2.3.6'
             })]
end




  describe 'cluster member nodes lookup - wait until all join' do

     my_node = {
      service: 'my_service',
      node: '1',
      dc: 'us',
  }

    before(:context) do

      cluster_members_stubs = get_cluster_members_stubs
      @chef_run = ChefSpec::ServerRunner.new(platform: 'ubuntu', version: '14.04') do |node, server|
        node.automatic[:common] = my_node

        # This is the current server data (first ha)
        server.create_node(cluster_members_stubs[0])

        # This is the second ha server data
        server.create_node(cluster_members_stubs[1])

      end

      Thread.new {
        @chef_run.converge(described_recipe) do
          @chef_run.resource_collection.insert(
              Chef::Resource::Service.new('my_service', @chef_run.run_context))
        end
      }

      timeout = 15 # should be enough for converging...
      started = Time.now

      until (@chef_run.node[:my_service] != nil &&
          @chef_run.node[:my_service][:cluster_members] != nil &&
          @chef_run.node[:my_service][:cluster_members].length === 2) ||
          Time.now - started > timeout
        puts "[#{Time.now - started}] waiting for converge...#{@chef_run.node[:my_service]}"
        sleep 1
      end

      puts "[#{Time.now - started}] Converged!...#{@chef_run.node[:my_service][:cluster_members]}"
    end

    it 'should find the first 2 registered nodes' do
      expect(@chef_run.node[:my_service][:cluster_members].to_a).to match_array(['1.2.3.4', '1.2.3.5'])
    end

    context 'add 20003 in 3 seconds' do

      before(:context) do
        cluster_members_stubs = get_cluster_members_stubs
        sleep 3
        @chef_run.create_node(cluster_members_stubs[2])

        timeout = 20 # should be enough for converging...
        started = Time.now

        until (@chef_run.node[:my_service] != nil &&
            @chef_run.node[:my_service][:cluster_members] != nil &&
            @chef_run.node[:my_service][:cluster_members].length === 3) ||
            Time.now - started > timeout
          puts "[#{Time.now - started}] waiting for recipe to find our new member...#{@chef_run.node[:my_service]}"
          sleep 1
        end
        puts "[#{Time.now - started}] Found!...#{@chef_run.node[:my_service][:cluster_members]}"
      end

      it 'should find it once added' do
        expect(@chef_run.node[:my_service][:cluster_members].to_a).to match_array(['1.2.3.4', '1.2.3.5', '1.2.3.6'])
      end
    end
  end
```

When running Chef spec on this code (by running `chef exec rspec spec/configure_spec.rb -f d`), the test passes but i get this exception:

```
  usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
    [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
    [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
    [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
    should add all members to my_service.conf as ha.initial_hosts list
  cluster member nodes lookup - wait until all join
[4.4e-05] waiting for converge...
[1.003424] waiting for converge...
[2.003765] waiting for converge...
[3.014148] waiting for converge...
[4.027826] waiting for converge...
[5.034108] waiting for converge...
[6.035726] waiting for converge...
[7.039808] waiting for converge...
[8.04352] waiting for converge...
[9.045821] waiting for converge...

usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
    [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
    [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
    [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
[10.046889] Converged!...#<Set: {"1.2.3.4", "1.2.3.5"}>
    should find the first 2 registered nodes
    add 20003 in 3 seconds
[5.4e-05] waiting for recipe to find our new member...

================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'template[/etc/my_service/my_service.conf]'
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::UserIDNotFound
--------------------------------
cannot determine user id for 'dev', does the user exist on this system?

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/folders/21/x4vz7kyd19z30q2f_jvn_g3c0000gn/T/chefspec20200202-59873-1g2naeefile_cache_path/cookbooks/my_service/recipes/configure.rb

 85: template "#{node[:my_service][:config_file]}" do
 86:   source "my_service.conf.erb"
 87:   owner "dev"
 88:   group "dev"
 89:   mode "0644"
 90:   notifies :restart, 'service[my_service]', :delayed 
 91:   variables(
 92:       {
 94:           :node_id => node_id,
 95:           :cluster_members => cluster_nodes,
                    ...
 99:       }
100:   )
102: end

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/folders/21/x4vz7kyd19z30q2f_jvn_g3c0000gn/T/chefspec20200202-59873-1g2naeefile_cache_path/cookbooks/my_service/recipes/configure.rb:85:in `from_file'

template("/etc/my_service/my_service.conf") do
  action [:create]
  default_guard_interpreter :default
  source "my_service.conf.erb"
  declared_type :template
  cookbook_name "my_service"
  recipe_name "configure"
  owner "dev"
  group "dev"
  mode "0644"
  variables {:node_id=>"node1", :cluster_members=>"1.2.3.4,1.2.3.5,1.2.3.6"}
  path "/etc/my_service/my_service.conf"
  verifications []
end

System Info:
------------
chef_version=15.4.45
platform=ubuntu
platform_version=14.04
ruby=ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-darwin17]
program_name=/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/rspec
executable=/Users/dan_mordechay/dev/af-chef/cookbooks/my_service/spec/configure_spec.rb

#<Thread:0x00007fbb70636d88@/Users/dan_mordechay/dev/af-chef/cookbooks/my_service/spec/configure_spec.rb:138 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    26: from /Users/dan_mordechay/dev/af-chef/cookbooks/my_service/spec/configure_spec.rb:139:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
    25: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chefspec-7.4.0/lib/chefspec/server_runner.rb:35:in `converge'
    24: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chefspec-7.4.0/lib/chefspec/solo_runner.rb:122:in `converge'
    23: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/client.rb:699:in `converge'
    22: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/client.rb:699:in `catch'
    21: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/client.rb:704:in `block in converge'
    20: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/runner.rb:130:in `converge'
    19: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/forwardable.rb:230:in `execute_each_resource'
    18: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:94:in `execute_each_resource'
    17: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
    16: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
    15: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:86:in `step'
    14: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:115:in `call_iterator_block'
    13: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:96:in `block in execute_each_resource'
    12: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/runner.rb:132:in `block in converge'
    11: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `run_all_actions'
    10: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `each'
     9: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `block in run_all_actions'
     8: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/runner.rb:74:in `run_action'
     7: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chefspec-7.4.0/lib/chefspec/extensions/chef/resource.rb:42:in `run_action'
     6: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/resource.rb:585:in `run_action'
     5: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/provider.rb:175:in `run_action'
     4: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/provider.rb:197:in `process_resource_requirements'
     3: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:315:in `run'
     2: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:315:in `each'
     1: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:316:in `block in run'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:238:in `run': cannot determine user id for 'my_service', does the user exist on this system? (Chef::Exceptions::UserIDNotFound)
    26: from /Users/dan_mordechay/dev/af-chef/cookbooks/my_service/spec/configure_spec.rb:139:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
    25: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chefspec-7.4.0/lib/chefspec/server_runner.rb:35:in `converge'
    24: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chefspec-7.4.0/lib/chefspec/solo_runner.rb:122:in `converge'
    23: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/client.rb:699:in `converge'
    22: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/client.rb:699:in `catch'
    21: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/client.rb:704:in `block in converge'
    20: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/runner.rb:130:in `converge'
    19: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/forwardable.rb:230:in `execute_each_resource'
    18: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:94:in `execute_each_resource'
    17: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
    16: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
    15: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:86:in `step'
    14: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:115:in `call_iterator_block'
    13: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:96:in `block in execute_each_resource'
    12: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/runner.rb:132:in `block in converge'
    11: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `run_all_actions'
    10: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `each'
     9: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `block in run_all_actions'
     8: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/runner.rb:74:in `run_action'
     7: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chefspec-7.4.0/lib/chefspec/extensions/chef/resource.rb:42:in `run_action'
     6: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/resource.rb:585:in `run_action'
     5: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/provider.rb:175:in `run_action'
     4: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/provider.rb:197:in `process_resource_requirements'
     3: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:315:in `run'
     2: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:315:in `each'
     1: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:316:in `block in run'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.4.45/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:238:in `run': template[/etc/my_service/my_service.conf] (my_service::configure line 85) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::UserIDNotFound: cannot determine user id for 'my_service', does the user exist on this system? (Chef::Exceptions::UserIDNotFound)
[1.004191] Found!...#<Set: {"1.2.3.4", "1.2.3.5", "1.2.3.6"}>
      should find it once added
```

Comment: when do you get the error? the "other recipe" executes before or after the error? what do you mean by "test run"? please **clarify** the question

Comment: @Mr. clarification: when i test my recipe i test it in isolation - i do not load the other recipies. i get the error when i run the my chefspec test, so my question is if theres a way to "setup" my test to mock that user that it cant find. BTW: when i had a "root" owner, chefspec didnt throw this exception. only when i changed the owner to another user, it started screaming that it cant find it...

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @danfromisrael: please share a code snippet

Comment: @DracoAter i edited the question and added a snippet

Comment: @danfromisrael And the test code?

Comment: @Mr. & Draco Ater i've added a very detailed code snippet. i understand now my code complexity somehow caused it

Comment: @DracoAter :point_up:

Comment: "When running Chef spec...", how do you run it?

Comment: @Mr. `chef exec rspec spec/configure_spec.rb -f d`